# How to Convert Http Client Response into Dictionary in robot framework

Tags: java, httprequest, robotframework

I am hitting a url and getting the data which is a response data .I want to convert this response into dictionary But it gives this error   TypeError: 'com.github.hi_fi.httpclient.domain.ResponseData' object is not iterable
I want to convert response to dictionary to get id value from my response

Code:

```
Create Session  httpbin   ${testServer}    debug=True
    Set Test Variable  &{headers}  Authorization=${Token}
    &{data}=  Create Dictionary  name=robot  gender=male  email=robot64@gmail  status=Active
 
    ${resp}=  Post Request   httpbin   /public/v1/users   ${data}  headers=${headers}
    log   ${resp}
    
    &{dit}=  Convert to Dictionary  ${resp}  //Fails 
    log  &{dit}
```

I am able to get id by  ${responseId}=  Find Json Element  ${resp}   $..id

response :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuPLf.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or errors, take the time to copy & paste them. The error in the log screenshot is different than what you are saying it is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Requests library / `Post Request` return a response object *(e.g. headers, the request itself, other properties)*, not just the payload string. Thus it fails in converting as a dict.

You can get the payload string with `${resp.content}`, or if you're sure it is a json, you can get it straight as parsed dictionary with `${resp.json()}`.

Comment: I am getting following error "Resolving variable '${resp.json()}' failed: TypeError: 'com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap' object is not callable" 
    &{dit}  Convert to Dictionary   ${resp}.json()
    log    &{dit}  Also ${resp.json()} did not work

Comment: Which robot framework library are you using for the http requests? By the class names in the errors, this looks like a java one; check its interface docs, and how to get the content of the response payload. Go with the one returning it as a string - in python's Requests library that would be `response.content`, and with that string in hand, parse it as a json, to get a dictionary. Keep in mind `Create Dictionary` will not do that for you - it expects key=value pairs, and you will be passing a json string.

Comment: You still haven't changed the question's body, to include the errors as text.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, Yes I am using java library with robot framework, the response that i was getting was in form of dictionary and I had to convert to json through java code ( as I did not have json java robot library )